# ReferenceError: SendGridMessage is not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

All I wont to do is use sendgrid from a mvc razor view page. This is my best attempt, please help. 
Why do I get this error "SendGridMessage is not defined",

I am trying to adapt the example from https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp
I have added the name space in web.config

```
 <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Net.Mail" />
    <add namespace="SendGrid" />
  </namespaces>
```

Here is the code

```
<input type="button" value="Send Booking" class="btn k-button" onclick="sendGrid1()" />

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function sendGrid1() {

                        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();

                        myMessage.From = new MailAddress("john@example.com");
                        myMessage.AddTo("john@example.com");
                        myMessage.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library";

                        //Add the HTML and Text bodies
                        myMessage.Html = "<p>Hello World!</p>";
                        myMessage.Text = "Hello World plain text!";


                        var username = "xxxx";
                        var pswd = "xxxxxxx";
                        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pswd);

                        // Create an Web transport for sending email.
                        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

                        // Send the email.
                        // You can also use the **DeliverAsync** method, which returns an awaitable task.
                        transportWeb.Deliver(myMessage,function(err, json) {
                            if (err) { console.error(err); }
                            console.log(json);
                        });

                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: you are putting csharp code, within  javascript tags, thus confusing csharp with Javascript

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to use this code in your C# code-behind (if using Web Forms) or in your Controller (in case of MVC). Copy and paste this code on the website you mentioned in C#.

I would recommend using NuGet to download this library. In Visual Studio, Tools --> NuGet Package Manager --> Manage NuGet packages for Solution...Write SendGrid and install the required libraries in your project. Then write the following code as given on the web site.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using SendGridMail;
using SendGridMail.Transport;

SendGrid mail = SendGrid.GetInstance();
mail.From = new MailAddress("you@youremail.com");
mail.AddTo("test@sendgrid.com");
mail.Subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
mail.Text = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";

var credentials = new NetworkCredential(api_user, api_key);
var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
transportWeb.Deliver(mail);
```

The only thing you need to have is to get an API key, the link is here:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/api_keys.html

Hope this helps.